# Counting the number of times button is clicked during my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am doing a program on a class list counter. I have one program, in frame 5 underneath "Population Count" and where it says 0, it is meant to increase by one for every time the button "Add to classlist" is clicked every time. I tried many different methods but all of those I tried never seem to work. It would be appreciative if anyone can help.

Here is my coding so far, the rest I have done for my class list counter

```
import pickle
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Class:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

class ClassPopulation():
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Class population")

        self.firstnameVar = StringVar()
        self.lastnameVar = StringVar()

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        Label(frame1, text = "First name").grid(row = 1,
            column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.firstnameVar,
              width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        Label(frame2, text = "Last name").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.lastnameVar,
              width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame3 = Frame(window)
        frame3.pack()
        Button(frame3, text = "Add to classlist", 
            command = self.processAdd).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        frame4 = Frame(window)
        frame4.pack()
        Label(frame4, text = "Population Count").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        frame5 = Frame(window)
        frame5.pack()
        Label(frame5, text = "0").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        population = 0

    def population(label):
        population = 0

    def mbutton():
        global population
        population +=1
        label.config(text=str(population))

        self.classList = self.loadClass()
        self.current = 0

        if len(self.classList) > 0:
            self.setClass()

    def saveClass(self):
        outfile = open("Population.dat", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.classList, outfile)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Class Population","New name registered")
        outfile.close()

    def loadClass(self):
        if not os.path.isfile("Population.dat"):
            return [] # Return an empty list
        try:
            infile = open("Population.dat", "rb")
            classList = pickle.load(infile)
        except EOFError:
            classList = []

        infile.close()
        return classList

    def processAdd(self):
        classList = Class(self.firstnameVar.get(), self.lastnameVar.get())
        self.classList.append(classList)
        self.saveClass()


    def setClass(self):
        self.firstnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].firstname)
        self.lastnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].lastname)


ClassPopulation()
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a **global** `population` you need to declare `self.population = 0` in your `__init__` method and to increment `self.population` in your button click handler. It is normally also considered good practice to have a class method to get the value.

Comment: Are you able to explain that in a coding format? Thanks

Comment: If you mean adding a useless method like "def get_population(self): return self.population", this is normally considered bad practice by core python developers, starting with Guido van Rossum.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution**: if all you want to do is, have the population count, and increment it on each button click:

```
import pickle
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Class:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

class ClassPopulation():
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Class population")

        self.firstnameVar = StringVar()
        self.lastnameVar = StringVar()

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        Label(frame1, text = "First name").grid(row = 1,
              column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.firstnameVar,
              width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        Label(frame2, text = "Last name").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.lastnameVar,
              width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame3 = Frame(window)
        frame3.pack()
        Button(frame3, text = "Add to classlist", 
            command = self.processAdd).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        frame4 = Frame(window)
        frame4.pack()
        Label(frame4, text = "Population Count").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        frame5 = Frame(window)
        frame5.pack()
        Label(frame5, text = "0").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        # population = 0
        self.population = 0 # made it a class attr

    # def population(label):
    #     population = 0

    def add_population(self):
        # having it separate can help in modification or enhancement
        self.population +=1

    def mbutton():
        # global population
        # population +=1
        self.add_population() # increment 
        label.config(text=str(population))

        self.classList = self.loadClass()
        self.current = 0

        if len(self.classList) > 0:
            self.setClass()

    def saveClass(self):
        outfile = open("Population.dat", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.classList, outfile)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Class Population","New name registered")
        outfile.close()

    def loadClass(self):
        if not os.path.isfile("Population.dat"):
            return [] # Return an empty list
        try:
            infile = open("Population.dat", "rb")
            classList = pickle.load(infile)
        except EOFError:
            classList = []

        infile.close()
        return classList

    def processAdd(self):
        classList = Class(self.firstnameVar.get(), self.lastnameVar.get())
        self.classList.append(classList)
        self.saveClass()


    def setClass(self):
        self.firstnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].firstname)
        self.lastnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].lastname)


ClassPopulation()
```

---

**Edit 1**: I have added the complete code, with my suggested changes - previous statements are commented, so you know the changes.

Comment: Doing this i think requires 2 solutions at the same time. How do you do that, perhaps in a coding format will help.

Comment: made population a class attribute to make it more elegant, and set the increment method separate. in mbutton() instead of direct increment, made a call to add_population() - as you can add other statements there if need to. Overall it's same as your above code, just added/edited 2 3 lines.
P.S. I didn't get your comment fully - do you want the full code ?

Comment: Nabeel hello, are you there